# Calling a function inside of JSONB?

Tags: postgresql, functions, json

Is is possible to call a function, like `now()` when inserting/updating a JSONB column in Postgres?

I was thinking something like the following where `time` would be set to the return value of `now()`:
`SELECT '{"value": 5, "time": now()}'::JSONB;`

Comment: If one of the answers works for you, can you mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, [JSON doesn't support a special date type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29269257/124486), [(neither does JavaScript)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures), [JSONB only supports](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html)

- `string`
- `number`
- `boolean`
- `null`

So just use string interpolation, it'll get stored the same way:

```
SELECT (
  '{"value": 5, "time": "' || now() || '" }'
)::JSONB;
```

If you're trying to simply get `NOW()` from the server in one call, you can certainly do that using `jsonb_set`, or jsonb concatenation (`||`). Here are [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html)

```
SELECT '{"value": 5}'::JSONB || jsonb_build_object('time', now());
```

In a third party library this may look like..

```
INSERT INTO table (json)
VALUES ( ? || jsonb_build_object('time', now()) );
```

It's still ugly. I wouldn't store a datatime in a JSONB, unless I had to:

- It will be slow.
- It will take *more* space.

As an aside, one of the alternatives to JSONB that Pg could have chosen is [BSON which doesn't store dates as strings.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON).

Comment: That works, but is there a way to pull something like that off when using a library like [node-postgres](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg)?

Comment: @DaveJohansen updated.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you mentioned [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) `now()` "as json value" does not need `jsonb_build_object` if you pass it as prepared statement, Eg:

```
var pg = require('pg');
var conString = 'postgres://n@10.1.10.199/b';
var pgClient = new pg.Client(conString);
pgClient.connect();

var query = 'select concat(\'{"value": 5, "time": "\',$2::timestamptz,\'"}\')::jsonb, $1::timestamptz';
var values = ['now()','now()'];
var cb = function(err, result) {
  console.log(result.rows);
};

pgClient.query(
  {
    name: 'get some',
    text: query,
    values: values
  }
  , cb
);
```

shows:

```
[
  {
    concat: {
      time: '2016-12-09 14:16:28.539636+00',
      value: 5
    },
    timestamptz: FriDec09201614: 16: 28GMT+0000(GMTStandardTime)
  }
]
```